# How do you unselect vertices without a middle mouse button?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edit-mode

I know with a mouse, you can press <kbd>b</kbd> in edit mode and then box select using the middle mouse button to deselect vertices (or edges, faces, etc.)
How do you do this if you don't have a middle mouse button?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Blender you really have to have a middle-mouse-button, but if you don't own a 3 button mouse, you can emulate one in the preferences.

1. Open User Preferences <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.
2. Switch the the Input tab.
3. Enable Emulate 3 Button Mouse.

You can now use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Left-Mouse to perform tasks normally done with the middle mouse button.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative solution would be to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> before dragging with left mouse button, which will deselect vertices within lasso area. This method also doesn't require middle mouse button:

[image: Lasso-deselect]

Omitting <kbd>Shift</kbd> (just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>LMB</kbd>) will lasso-select vertices.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running the KDE desktop (commonly under Linux), <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> is a system combination that allows you to move the current Window. [Aldrik's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/919/2509) can work, but you need to first disable (or change) KDE's response to this action.

One way to do this is to disable *all* system shortcuts for Blender:

Right click on the Blender title bar, and then select *More Actions* and then *Special Application Settings...*

[image: Special Application Settings Menu]

Then under the *Appearances & Fixes* tab: check *Ignore global shortcuts*, select the *Force* option, and select the *Yes* radio button. Save the settings.

[image: Appearances and Fixes Tab]

The <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> combination will now act like the middle mouse button in Blender.