# Can the full features of Blender be used with a trackpad?

Tags: osx

I'm not interested recommendations for the best hardware, but whether Blender's full functionality-- all that zooming and selecting stuff-- can be realized with only a trackpad.

Comment: Short answer, _yes_, but it gets quite cumbersome. Best to invest in a mouse and use the emulation settings available.

Comment: I work with a trackpad all the time, but I am getting a mouse soon because it is definitely easier to use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use it to an extent, but from experience, it quickly becomes quite cumbersome. You tend to lose a lot of precision as the space to move in is a bit cramped and overall it is not worth taking the time to get adjusted to and or customizing it to work better.

*For example:* To zoom, I have to swipe the edge of the trackpad, this quickly gets annoying and it often passes the point where I want to stop.

I *highly* recommend investing in a mouse instead and using the *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* option in the user preferences.

Related:

- [How do you unselect vertices without a middle mouse button?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/917/how-do-you-unselect-vertices-without-a-middle-mouse-button)
- [How to emulate a Number Pad and 3 Button Mouse?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124/how-to-emulate-a-number-pad-and-3-button-mouse)
- [Zoom in and out without a mouse wheel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1508/zoom-in-and-out-without-a-mouse-wheel)
- [How can I control the viewport without a mouse?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/how-can-i-control-the-viewport-without-a-mouse)

Comment: I think you are incorrect regarding zooming. Zooming is performed using pinching.

Comment: @Jonny I was using an example, on _my_ laptop, I have to swipe the trackpad.

Comment: Just saying that I am using pinching all the time in Blender on my Mac. It's possible that older OSes and Macs don't support the gesture.

Comment: What does the emulate 3 button mouse do?

Comment: @AnsonSavage It lets alt + LMB act like the MMB (left and middle mouse buttons).

Answer (score 33):

On modern Mac OS X, it seems you can:

- Two-finger vertical scroll to rotate along horizontal axis perpendicular to view
- Two-finger "spin" to rotate around up axis
  or Two-finger horizontal scroll to rotate around up axis
- Two-finger pinch to zoom
- or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + two-finger vertical/horizontal scroll to zoom
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + two-finger vertical scroll to pan along up axis
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + two-finger vertical scroll to pan along horizontal axis perpendicular to view
- RIGHT click and drag to translate selected object
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> click and drag to lasso select

Comment: This is now (as of 2015) the best answer. Tested in blender 2.74 and works like a charm. Wish I had had this years ago. @Alec is there also a good mapping now for what was the numpad functions?

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add to @Alec's answer that there is a checkbox for "Natural Trackpad Direction". You can find this in the preferences panel, inside the Input tab. This option seems to invert the direction in which the rotation happens when you do a two-finger scroll.

It seems to be off by default, but to me it made more sense with it on. It feels more consistent with the way the mouse rotates.

Comment: Wish I had seen this earlier. Spent way too much time figuring out how to do this.

Comment: @Jose Vazquez's answer was really helpful to me. Just to update that, in Blender 2.83.0, the "Natural Trackpad Direction" option is no longer inside the Input tab. It has been moved to the Navigation tab instead.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution I've found so far (and I've done this on Windows too) is *User Preferences > Input > 3D View > Rotate View and Move view*. Remap the "Center Mouse" to <kbd>~</kbd> (tilde) and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> respectively.

YouTube video that showed me this option: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYz3EAxmyrQ

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @alec Karabiner Elements can be useful to access the numpad. Here is part of my preferences.json file which causes fn+1..0 to send 1..0 from the numpad so views can be selected in Blender without a physical numpad or always using the menus:

```
            "simple_modifications": [
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "1",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": [
                                "fn"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "key_code": "keypad_1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "2",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": [
                                "fn"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "key_code": "keypad_2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "3",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": [
                                "fn"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "key_code": "keypad_3"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "4",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": [
                                "fn"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "key_code": "keypad_4"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "5",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": [
                                "fn"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "key_code": "keypad_5"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "6",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": [
                                "fn"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "key_code": "keypad_6"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "7",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": [
                                "fn"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "key_code": "keypad_7"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "8",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": [
                                "fn"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "key_code": "keypad_8"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "9",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": [
                                "fn"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "key_code": "keypad_9"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "0",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": [
                                "fn"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "key_code": "keypad_0"
                    }
                }
            ],
```